# Boost::Signals2 slot with lambda expression fails using gcc6 on arm32

Tags: c++, boost, arm, signals, gcc6

I received the following code from a colleague, broken down to the bare minimum, using Boost::Signal2 and lambda expressions. It compiles with g++ 6.x and g++ 5.4.1 (the latter with argument -std=c++11).

It should print **i: 5 (should be 5)**

Using a gcc 6.4.1 (or 6.1.1) cross compiler for arm32 (arm-cortexa15-linux-gnueabihf-g++) and running on such a system, the output is **i: 0 (should be 5)**

Other architectures (x86_64) and compilers (gcc 5.4.1) work as expected.

When I change to code to use a signal instead of a slot, everything is ok.

My questions are:

1. Is this code really reliably supposed to output i: 5 (should be 5), or is this code buggy and worked only accidentally?
2. Or is there a bug in the ARM32 gcc6 compiler? (gcc 5 works)

Code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class LogBuffer : public std::streambuf
{   
public:
    LogBuffer()
    {   
    }   

    char m_buf[242 - 20];
};  

namespace boost
{   
    void assertion_failed(char const * p_expr,
                          char const *,
                          char const *, long)
    {   
        std::cerr << "FAILED: " << p_expr << std::endl;
    }   

    void assertion_failed_msg(char const *,
                              char const * msg,
                              char const *,
                              char const *, long)
    {   
        std::cerr << "FAILED: " << msg << std::endl;
    }   
} // namespace boost

void myfunction(void)
{   

    {   
        LogBuffer b;
        std::cout << "LogBuffer size: " << sizeof(LogBuffer) << std::endl;
    }   
    int i=5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    auto lambda = [i] { std::cerr << "i: " << i << " (should be 5)" << std::endl; };
    boost::signals2::signal<void()>::slot_type slot{lambda};
    slot();
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    myfunction();
}
```

Compile and run delivers the following output:

```
arm-cortexa15-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (GCC) 6.4.1 20170811
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Linux fctj-4a 4.4.109-g68c6f3c-fsm4_axm #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 2 05:37:09 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

LogBuffer size: 256
5
i: 0 (should be 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug.

Can you reduce the reproducer? Say,

- what happens if you disable optimizations
- what happens if you remove the LogBuffer?
- What happens if you remove the slot and use it as a signal
- What happens if you keep the signals stuff and just invoke the lambda directly?
- What happens if you invoke the lambda before creating the slot
- What happens if you don't even create the slot, and call the lambda directly?
- What happens if you further also remove the signals2 header.
- What happens if you terminate in the assert handlers (perhaps you are getting asserts at a time when `std::cout` is not yet initialized//available)

If you reduce it to the simplest possible core and still have the failure, you will at least know whether to file a bug at Boost or GCC

Answer (score 0):

This is what I already did:

1. -O0, -O1: bug does not show up i: 5 (should be 5)
2. -O2: bug shows up 0 (should be 5)
3. remove Logbuffer: 5 (should be 5)
4. using a signal Signal: 0 should be 5
5. calling lambda directly (5 should be 5)
6. using i after calling slot (e.g printing): 5 (should be 5)
7. using i[100]: first element becomes zero, others unaffected
8. using x86_64 compiler : 5 should be 5

Others will follow. I am not sure how I can easily remove the signals2 header

Reiner

Comment: this is not answer - you should add this to the question - this is part of question